# I need help building openvibe sourcecode for lpc1768

Tags: build, arm, keil, mbed, lpc

I'm using keil for debugging lpc1768 and here is the link for downloading the source code:

http://openvibe.inria.fr/pub/src/openvibe-2.0.0-src.tar.xz

I need to build openvibe for an application project i am migrating to an lpc1768 baseboard but i dunno which directories and how i can do this and then use it when programming the microcontroller.

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OpenViBE is specific enough for you to consider routing this question to the OpenViBE community or to the lpc1768 rather than Stack Overflow. You can engage with the OpenViBE community at http://openvibe.inria.fr/forum

Good luck!

Comment: i dont see any reason as to why my topic is irrelevant to SOF community! you can consider the most general assumptions from my question and then answer if you will.

Comment: absolutely, you must be right - let's see how it goes, and if you eventually feel like moving forward might be something, just double check my first reply and give it a try